# Is this valid use of returning reference?

Tags: c++

Say I define a structure like this:

```
struct point {
   int x;
   int y;
}

const point & clone(point& pt) {
    point * new_pt;
    * new_pt = pt;   // copy info, new is called?
    return *new_pt;
}
```

My understanding is `*new_pt = pt` implicitly calls `new` and allocate necessary storage on the heap for the copied structure, so `new_pt` is not pointing to a temporary variable, and I can return the reference to it, is that right?

Comment: *"My understanding is `*new_pt = pt` implicitly calls new and allocate necessary storage on the heap for the copied structure"* Where did you get that idea? Please stop trying to learn C++ by trial and error, it will get you nowhere. Learn it systematically from a good book instead.

Comment: *"My understanding is *new_pt = pt implicitly calls new and allocate necessary storage on the heap for the copied structure"* Just out of curiosity why is that your understanding? That definitely does not happen. Check out this classic: http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/104/ watch the c++ version.

Comment: I don't understand why the hostile attitude of a question and example. The example was taken from the book "C++ Primer Plus" 6th edition 2011 on Page 400. The exact naming of variable was changed to make it a self-contained. The verbatim word from book is "A call to clone() conceals() the call to `new` ... " ... hence the better approach of using `unique_ptr`. But that is not the point of question. I was surpised a `new` is there, thus the quesiton.

Comment: If there is no new involved, just saying so is enough ... no need to over-judge and over-reach ...

Comment: The text you quoted seems unrelated to the code. Could be a printing error. (That book doesn't have a very good reputation. It's probably named to be confused with C++ Primer.)

Answer (score 2):

It does not `*new_pt = pt` will most likely crash (undefined behaviour actually) because `new_pt` points to nothing.

If you want to have the memory be allocated dynamically, you'll need to do a `new` at some point. But who's going to `delete` the memory then?

Your function should return an object or a `shared_ptr` (but you'll have to do a new anyway).

Answer (score 0):

> My understanding is *new_pt = pt implicitly calls new and allocate necessary storage on the heap for the copied structure

No.

```
point * new_pt;
```

`new_pt` has an undertermined value.

```
* new_pt = pt;
```

You are dereferencing `new_pt`, but it is undefined, which means you trigger undefined behavior (which will very likely result into a crash).

Your code tries to assign the value `new_pt` points to `pt` (effectively copying it).